# ¿Cómo obtener segundo y tercer valor más alto de una tabla en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy trabajando en la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A través de la siguiente consulta logro obtener el valor más alto que es '453 - Operaciones I Series',

```
SELECT TOP 1 NOMBRE, SUM(MONTODEBITO) AS MONTO
FROM PRUEBAOPEX
GROUP BY NOMBRE
ORDER BY MAX(MONTODEBITO) DESC
```

A través de la siguiente consulta obtengo solo el valor más alto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber como sería la consulta para obtener el segundo y tercer valor más alto de mi tabla, ambos de manera única como en la ejemplo que di.

Espero haberme dado a entender, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: un ejemplo de lo que queres como salida ayuda mucho mas...

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, ya puse un ejemplo de como busco que sea mi salida, con el valor más alto de mi tabla. Estoy buscando exactamente lo mismo para tanto el segundo como tercer valor más alto.

Comment: Con select top 3 obtengo los tres valores más altos. Pero yo necesito obtener por ejemplo únicamente el segundo, sin necesidad que me aparezca el primer valor más alto. Lo mismo con el tercero, sin que me aparezca ni el primer y segundo más alto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener el segundo valor más alto harías:

```
Select Top 1 nombre, monto
From
(
 SELECT top 2 NOMBRE, SUM(MONTODEBITO) AS MONTO
 FROM PRUEBAOPEX
 GROUP BY NOMBRE
 ORDER BY SUM(MONTODEBITO) DESC
) T
Order by T.Monto ASC;
```

Tu consulta original la **ordeno descendentemente** y selecciono los dos primeros registros, y sobre esta consulta aplico una más general pero esta vez los registros se **ordenarán ascendentemente** dejando al segundo registro de primero, entonces hago **Top 1** para seleccionar este registro.

Para obtener el tercer registro más alto solamente tienes que sustituir **Top 2** por **Top 3** en la consulta más interna.